# INNER JOIN WITH TWO CONDITIONS but only one exists

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT oc_product.product_id, oc_product.quantity, oc_product.price, oc_product_description.name, oc_product_description.description
FROM oc_product
INNER JOIN oc_produsct_description ON oc_product.product_id = oc_product_description.product_id
WHERE oc_product.prodsuct_id = 1 AND oc_prodDuct_description.landuage_id = 5
```

In this query oc_product_id = 1 exists, but oc_product_description.language_id = 5 doesn't exists.

However i want to get SELECT for product with id 1, if language 5 exists or not exists

Comment: Something like ? in regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `left join`:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.quantity, p.price, pd.name, pd.description
FROM oc_product p LEFT JOIN
     oc_product_description pd
     ON p.product_id = pd.product_id AND pd.language_id = 5
WHERE p.product_id = 1;
```

Notes:

- The condition on `language_id` needs to go into the `ON` clause or the outer join is transformed to an inner join.
- Use table aliases, they make the query easier to read and to write.

Comment: Yeah, that's it ! Thank u, dude !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN like this:

```
SELECT oc_product.product_id, oc_product.quantity, oc_product.price, oc_product_description.name, oc_product_description.description
FROM oc_product
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description ON oc_product.product_id = oc_product_description.product_id
WHERE oc_product.product_id = 1 AND oc_product_description.landuage_id = 5
```